# Where syntax error?

Tags: syntax

i have a problem. 
Latest [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tB9Yd/) 
I can't see error:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {   
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 30) {
            $(header).addClass("logo-two");
            $(header).removeClass("logo-one");
        } else {
            $(header).removeClass("logo-two");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: I'm learning jQuery. Script not working, i don't know where is error

Comment: You don't have a `header` variable.

Comment: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tB9Yd/1/) Nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Header isn't a variable that you've defined. You need to place quotations before and after header to refer to the DOM element. When you don't include those quotations jQuery expects a reference to a defined variable.

Here is what I would try:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {   
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 30) {
            $('.logo').addClass("two");
            $('.logo').removeClass("one");
        } else {
            $('.logo').removeClass("two");
        }
       });
    });
```

Or, you can define .logo as a jQuery object:

```
var logo = $('.logo');
$(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 30) {
            $(logo).addClass("two");
            $(logo).removeClass("one");
        } else {
            $(logo).removeClass("two");
        }
       });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, i change [code](http://jsfiddle.net/tB9Yd/2/), but problem is here. I don't know why

Comment: It looks like you changed the element thats being manipulated to the logo div. Here is the code you should be using:

        `$(document).ready(function() {   
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 30) {
                $('.logo').addClass("two");
                $('.logo').removeClass("one");
            } else {
                $('.logo').removeClass("two");
            }
        });
    });`

When you are targeting a class, you use ".". When targeting an ID you use "#", like in CSS.

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect your updated code.